# 403 Forbidden error when submitting tinymce content

Tags: php, encryption, http-status-code-403

I have a form where i have tinymce editor to get content section. whenever i submit the form it works when the tinymce has less data in it. When the data exceeds some amount it starts throwing 403 - forbidden error.

I increased the memory limit and execution time and nothing works.

I tried encrypting in JS and decrypting in PHP. In that case it works but i could not able to decrypt in PHP. Decryption results unreadable characters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was a server setting which blocks it. i got to know when i contact my hosting provider who unlocks it.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Do you know which what was blocking? Clause my server provider it's kinda weird and they don't know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the result of your mod_security rules. Depending on how strict they are they help better protect scripts from being hacked through vulnerabilities, generally those exploited via POST's.