# PHP MySQL String escaping failing and showing 403 error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php project which works on the following method:

- The backend has textarea with rich editor (tinymce)

Here is the code of backend that works on submit:

Update.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);

//collect form data
extract($_POST);

//very basic validation
if ($categoryId == '') {
    $error[] = 'Invalid id.';
}

if ($categoryName == '') {
    $error[] = 'Please enter the Category Title .';
}

if (!isset($error)) {

    try {

        $categorySlug = slug($categoryName);

        //insert into database
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE post_category SET categoryName = :categoryName, categorySlug = :categorySlug, metatitle=:metatitle, meta_desc=:meta_desc, top_content=:top_content,bottom_content=:bottom_content WHERE categoryId = :categoryId');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':categoryName' => $categoryName,
            ':categorySlug' => $categorySlug,
            ':metatitle' => $metatitle,
            ':meta_desc' => $meta_desc,
            ':top_content' => $top_content,
            ':bottom_content' => $bottom_content,
            ':categoryId' => $categoryId
        ));

        //redirect to categories  page
        header('Location: categories.php?action=updated');
        exit;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Here is what error I am facing:

Whenever I add formatting to text entered in top content textarea (tinymce) like add link or make text justify and press update. I am getting 403 error and data is not udpated in DB.

Here are my findings:

the code from textarea is not being escaped and shows errors.

I have tried adding; mysql_real_escape_string, htmlspecialchars but they both are not working.

Any help would be appreciated so that the formatting, link or justifications etc from textarea rich editor works and data is saved in database with no errors.

Thanks,

Comment: 403 is a Forbidden error and should not be caused by anything thrown here. If you take most of the code out, it will most likely still give that error.

Comment: I'd caution you about using `extract` because it could lead to unexpected variable updates (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php even cautions against using this on user-submitted data like this). Additionally, you shouldn't need to call `mysql_real_escape_string` yourself, because prepared statements automatically escape values that are passed in via parameterization like you're doing.

Comment: To debug this further, you could easily add some `error_log` statements to ensure code that you're expecting to execute is executing (e.g. `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { error_log('post submit is set'); ...`, `if (!isset($error)) { error_log('no errors'); ...`. Or use `var_dump($variable); die();` and view the POST request in your browser's Network tab in developer tools.

Comment: As a note, `mysql_real_escape_string` will not work because 1) mysql_* functions are deprecated and removed as of PHP7.0, and mysqli_* functions are not compatible with PDO

Comment: If i dont use formatting in tinymce editor, then the code works fine and no errors occur. But when formatting in tinymce is applied, i get 403 error

Comment: do you face this issue on production or local? is it shared hosting?

Comment: It's probably related to mod_security, according to http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=22532 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496961/403-forbidden-error-when-submitting-tinymce-content